# how to execute gradle wrapper/gradlew command in android studio in windows

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am using gradle with android project in android studio, I wanna run `gradlew`command in the terminal in android studio, while I got gradlew command not found error.

My gradle wrapper is in the directory:

`"C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\bin"`

In this directory, there are following contents:

1. Directory named .gradle
2. File named gradle
3. File named gradle.bat.

I've tried to run
    `"gradle -v"` 
in this directory, it works fine.

But when I tried to run

```
gradle wrapper --gradle-version 4.1
```

**I got the error ：**

> "Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':wrapper'.
>   Cannot write to file 'C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar' specified for property 'jarFile', as ancestor 'C:\Use
>   rs\Administrator.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\gradle-4.1\bin\gradle' is not a directory.”

My project is in the directory `D:\ASWorkspace\MyApp`, I'm puzzled about if I wanna to execute gradlew command, I should execute it in which directory? in my android project or gradle project? and how to execute it without error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I should execute it in which directory? in my android project or
>   gradle project? and how to execute it without error?

`gradlew` should be executed from the project directory.

If you are using android studio, then simply switch to Terminal tab located at the bottom:

[image: Terminal]

And execute your `gradlew` commands.

Comment: thank you for your patient answer, I've created a new project, and it works, the problem may be the previous project is transformed from eclipse, and it's lack of some gradle file

Comment: @gesanri That explains. You need to have gradlew.bar configured properly in order to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run directly from Android Studio Terminal, you have to go:

**File > Settings > Tools > Terminal**

Then put on **Shell path** the directory to your terminal, like so:
`C:\Program Files\Git\git-cmd.exe`.

To execute Gradle command on Windows, you should go to Root directory of your project and then execute command: `./gradlew command`.

Also, you can see all tasks of gradle project using: `./gradlew tasks`.